# Can't select the button I want Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I'm working on my Unity project. And i faced a weird problem, where my cursor selects the bottom buttons when it should select the one it points to: [image: No cursor is visible in the screenshot. Imagine that it is on the 2nd button of the top line]
How can i fix it? I already tried to remove/create new buttons components, restart unity, played with transitions, but it didn't help.

By the way, when i disable "Maximize on Play" it works fine! I guess that there are problems with button position.

Another note: I used Horizontal Layout Group on my buttons lines.

Comment: No cursor is visible in the screenshot. imagine that it is on the 2nd button in the top line

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your UI needs Canvas scaler, that helps you with different resolutions.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-CanvasScaler.html

If that doesn't help, try debug your UI on different resolutions. You can change it in the left corner, where "Free Aspect" text is.

Comment: I already have Canvas Scaler on my parent object. When i saw your answer i immediately tried to change evething that i could in this, but it didn't helped.
About debugging: i noticed that problems with buttons starts when the screen scales to 4:3